# How to use generate_series to get the sum of values in a weekly interval

Tags: sql, postgresql, generate-series

I'm having trouble using `generate_series` in a weekly interval. I have two examples here, one is in a monthly interval and it is working as expected. It is returning each month and the sum of the `facts.sends` values. I'm trying to do the same exact thing in a weekly interval, but the values are not being added correctly.

Monthly interval (Working):
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/a9SbDBpa9SMGxM3bk8fMAD/0

Weekly interval (Not working): https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tNxRbCxvgwswoaN7esDk5w/2

Comment: You're getting different results from `date_trunc('week', fact_date)` and `generate_series('2022-05-01', now(), '1 week')`

Comment: The problem with the second query is that it hardcodes the start of the date series to 2022-05-01 ; that’s a Sunday, while Postgres' `week`s start on Monday. Just changing 2022-05-01 to 2022-05-02 in the query should be enough. Or, more flexible, `date_trunc('week', '2022-05-01')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should generate a series that starts on Monday.

```sql
WITH range_values AS (
  SELECT date_trunc('week', min(fact_date)) as minval,
         date_trunc('week', max(fact_date)) as maxval
  FROM facts),

week_range AS (
  SELECT generate_series(date_trunc('week', '2022-05-01'::date), now(), '1 week') as week
  FROM range_values
),

grouped_facts AS (
  SELECT date_trunc('week', fact_date) as week,
    sends
  FROM facts
  WHERE
    fact_date >= '2022-05-20'
)

SELECT week_range.week,
       COALESCE(sum(sends)::integer, 0) AS total_sends
FROM week_range
LEFT OUTER JOIN grouped_facts on week_range.week = grouped_facts.week
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

[DB Fiddle.](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3sEbfAWHuUZi8Tavf2FxpH/0)

Comment: Note that this can be [simplified significantly](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tNxRbCxvgwswoaN7esDk5w/2). `range_values` and the `grouped_facts` where clause is unnecessary as `week_range` is already constrained. `grouped_facts` is unnecessary, one can do the `date_trunc('week', fact_date)` inline.